# jquery parallax position calculation

Tags: jquery, parallax

I want to apply a parallax effect to a background image which can be positioned everywhere in a page inside a DIV.

I try to find the "perfect" equation in order to see the background image entirely (from top to bottom) when document is scrolled, while having always image filling fully the DIV.

Finally I just want a parallax image in the middle of a page that always work whatever the image height and window height.

Here my script (it works but my calculations don't take care completely of the window height and image height ...)

```
$("#inner-container").on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.parallax-container').each(function() {
        var parallaxDivPosition = $(this).position().top;
        var parallaxHeight = $(this).height();
        var scrollPosition = scrollTop + windowHeight;
        if (parallaxDivPosition <= windowHeight && parallaxDivPosition+parallaxHeight >= 0) {
            var parallaxFactor = parallaxHeight/windowHeight;
            var parallaxShift = parallaxHeight*parallaxFactor;
            var parallaxImgPos = parallaxDivPosition-windowHeight;
            var imagePosition = Math.round(parallaxImgPos-parallaxShift)*0.2;
            $(this).children().css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0px, '+imagePosition+'px, 0px)');
        }
    })
})
```

here a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uccE4/12/

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. Finally it was simple (after writing two equations on a paper!!lol)

```
$('*').scroll(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.parallax-container').each(function() {
        var parallaxDivPosition = $(this).position().top;
        var parallaxHeight = $(this).height();
        var parallaxTop = parallaxDivPosition - windowHeight;
        var parallaxBottom = parallaxHeight + parallaxDivPosition;
        if (parallaxTop < 0 && parallaxBottom > 0) {
            var parallaxFactor = 50/(windowHeight+parallaxHeight);
            var parallaxposition = Math.abs(parallaxTop)*parallaxFactor;
            $(this).children().css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0px, '+-parallaxposition+'%, 0px)');
        }
    })
})
```

So when the bottom div image background is a the top of the window I will see the bottom of the image. When the top div image background is at the bottom of the window I will see the top of the image...

So whatever the height of the image or the height of the window, when I scroll I always will show the entire image...